# My batis - No typehandler found for property - mapping with collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm trying to fetch data using mybatis with spring boot. I created mapper interface as well as xml file with resultMap and query, but Im getting an error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property patientId

What can possibly be wrong with my solution?

Target Object:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO {

    private UUID patientId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<BandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO> bandDailySynchronizationStatistics;
}
```

Target inner object:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO {

    private LocalDate date;
    private long gsrCount;
    private long ibiCount;
    private long temperatureCount;
    private LocalDate synchronizationDate;
}
```

Mapper interface:

```
@Mapper
public interface PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsMapper {

    List<PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO> queryAll(@Param("patientIds")List<UUID> patientIds,
                                                                @Param("startDate") LocalDate startDate,
                                                                @Param("endDate") LocalDate endDate);

}
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="com.e1s.bambino.band.statistics.synchronization.mapper.PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsMapper">

    <resultMap type="com.e1s.bambino.band.statistics.synchronization.PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO"
               id="patientStatisticsMap">
        <result property="patientId" column="id"/>
        <result property="firstName" column="first_name"/>
        <result property="lastName" column="last_name"/>
        <collection property="bandDailySynchronizationStatistics"
                    ofType="com.e1s.bambino.band.statistics.synchronization.BandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO"
                    javaType="List"
                    resultMap="statisticsMap">
        </collection>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap type="com.e1s.bambino.band.statistics.synchronization.BandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO"
               id="statisticsMap">
        <result property="date" column="date"/>
        <result property="gsrCount" column="gsr_count"/>
        <result property="ibiCount" column="ibi_count"/>
        <result property="temperatureCount" column="temperature_count"/>
        <result property="synchronizationDate" column="synchronization_date"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="queryAll" resultMap="patientStatisticsMap">
        SELECT p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name FROM patient p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN band_daily_synchronization_statistics bs
        ON bs.patient_id = p.id
        WHERE p.id IN #{patientIds}
        AND (bs.id IS NULL OR bs.date BETWEEN #{startDate} AND #{endDate})
    </select>
</mapper>
```

I put mapper interface in

```
src/main/java/com/e1s/bambino/band/statistics/synchronization/BandDailySynchronizationStatisticsMapper.java
```

Corresponding xml is in:

```
src/main/resources/com/e1s/bambino/band/statistics/synchronization/PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsMapper.xml
```

I injected mapper into my service via constructor.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BandDailySynchronizationStatisticsService {

    private final PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsMapper mapper;
    
    public List<PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO> searchBandDailySynchronizationStatistics(BandDailySynchronizationStatisticsSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        List<PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsDTO> allForPatients = mapper.queryAll(searchCriteria.getPatientIds(), searchCriteria.getStartDate(),
                searchCriteria.getEndDate());
        return allForPatients;
    }
```

Exception:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'com/e1s/bambino/band/statistics/synchronization/PatientBandDailySynchronizationStatisticsMapper.xml'. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property patientId
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:123)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.loadXmlResource(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:179)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.parse(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperRegistry.addMapper(MapperRegistry.java:72)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMapper(Configuration.java:819)
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:80)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property patientId
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.ResultMapping$Builder.validate(ResultMapping.java:151)
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.ResultMapping$Builder.build(ResultMapping.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.MapperBuilderAssistant.buildResultMapping(MapperBuilderAssistant.java:446)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.buildResultMappingFromContext(XMLMapperBuilder.java:393)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:280)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:254)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElements(XMLMapperBuilder.java:246)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:119)
    ... 81 more
```

Thanks in advance for all replys.

Comment: The XML file should be in `src/main/resources/com/e1s/bambino/band/statistics/synchronization/mapper ` directory. Otherwise, the build tool (i.e. maven or gradle) does not copy the XML file to the target directory when building the project.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I'm still missing something. However logs in stact trace are now without org.springframework logs

Comment: You should edit the question and update the stack trace (and the title if necessary).

Comment: The `namespace` specified in the XML contains 'mapper' in the package name. Try removing it.

Comment: Thanks, xml is now in action, however I have some problems parsing it. I changed question topic and description and tomorrow will try to work on that issue with type handler

Comment: To map UUID, you may need to write a custom type handler. If you store UUID into a CHAR-ish column, it would look something like [this](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/6136b99975f1d586d0464d8cb43fb7db20d124d4/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/uuid_test/UUIDTypeHandler.java). If the column is PostgreSQL's UUID type, see the example implementation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622573/1261766). And read the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/) for how to register custom type handler.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to help, but for test purposes I use in memory H2, which gives so far:Data conversion error converting "OTHER to UUID"; SQL statement:
SELECT p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name FROM patient p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN band_daily_synchronization_statistics bs
        ON bs.patient_id = p.id
        WHERE p.id IN (?)
        AND (bs.id IS NULL OR bs.date BETWEEN ? AND ?) [22018-200]

Comment: Please create a demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) that reproduces the same error and upload it on your GitHub repo. Then I'll take a look. FYI, there already are some executable example projects [1](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-60613619) [2](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/gh-1609) .